# Given a positive sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that the infinite sum of $\{a_n\}$ is convergent, changing the order of summation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove this theorem by showing that the sum of any reordering of the values is less or equal than the original sum and also it's larger or equal then the original sum.

I don't need a full proof as am trying to figure it out on my own so hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S_n$ and $R_n$ denote the $n$th partial sums of the original and rearranged sequences, respectively. Also, let $S = \lim S_n = \sup S_n$ and $R = \lim R_n = \sup R_n$. ($R$ and $S$ exist as limits in $[0,\infty]$ since the terms of both sequences are nonnegative. Furthermore, $S$ is finite by assumption, although we don't really need that fact; the result is still true if $S$ is $+\infty$.)

For a fixed $n$, there's some $m \geq n$ such that the first $m$ terms of the rearranged sequence include the first $n$ terms of the original (and perhaps other terms as well). Thus $S_n \leq R_m \leq R$. Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get $S \leq R$.

Now observe that the original sequence is a rearrangement of the rearranged sequence, so by the same argument as above, we also have $R \leq S$. It follows that $R = S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- For a finite subset of $\{a_n\}$ you can change the order of summation without changing its sum
- Since all the $a_n$ are positive, any sum of a  finite subset of $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above by the sum of the infinite sequence
- For any number strictly less than the sum of the infinite sequence, there is a  finite subset of $\{a_n\}$ whose sum is greater than that number

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the last hint?

Comment: If the sum of the infinite sequence is $s$ then for any $x< s$ there is a finite subset which adds up to more than $x$.  So rearranging that subset and possibly adding in more terms, you can show that any rearranged sequence has a finite number of initial terms which add up to more than $x$.